# heroku rake db:pull

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, heroku, taps

i am trying to pull my heroku apps database from the heroku server to my local machine.
i have done this a bunch like this...

```
$heroku db:pull mysql://root:mypass@localhost/app_data
```

Loaded Taps v0.3.24
Warning: Data in the database 'mysql://root:mypass@localhost/app_data' will be overwritten and will not be recoverable.

!    WARNING: Destructive Action
 !    This command will affect the app: heroku-app-9999
 !    To proceed, type "heroku-app-9999" or re-run this command with --confirm heroku-app-9999

```
> heroku-app-9999
```

**i get..**

```
!    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 !      <html>
 !        <head>
 !          <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 !          <style type="text/css">
 !            html, body, iframe { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; }
 !            iframe { display: block; width: 100%; border: none; }
 !          </style>
 !        <title>Application Error</title></head>
 !        </head>
 !        <body>
 !          <iframe src="//s3.amazonaws.com/heroku_pages/error.html">
 !            <p>Application Error</p>
 !          </iframe>
 !        </body>
 !        </html>
```

**weird response i have never seen! what dose it mean?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a generic error page served from heroku. Check your logs to see what the exact error is.

Comment: i check my logs and it says i have an error: `2013-01-21T12:01:29+00:00 app[worker.1]: Don't know how to build task 'jobs:work'` what dose that mean?